# Adding Databases Programmatically with Kubernetes sidecar

Tags: api, rest, kubernetes, redisinsights

I've been playing with redis GUIs. I've managed to spin up a web-app called Redis-Commander on K8s. I use an init-container to run a script and inject a connection config file(json) into a specified directory via volumes so that it loads the redis instances automatically on launching the app.

I was also looking at another app called [RedisInsight](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/ri/). The docs say you can add [databases programmatically](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/ri/using-redisinsight/api/) using their REST API.  Been told I can use a sidecar to achieve this but I'm not sure how to go about it. How would you use the sidecar to achieve this? Is there a better method?

URL : /api/instance/
Method : POST
Body Type: JSON
Auth required : NO

Comment: Why are you assuming a sidecar can be used for creating the db? I'm not sure how would that work, are you talking about a sidecar for the deployment of your apps? That doesn't make sense since it will add a db for each pod spawned.

Comment: @YaronIdan the dbs already exist and I'm just providing the connection config parameters for the Redis web app. With Redis-Commander I just had to inject the config file in a specified directory and when launched the Redis instances would be present without the requirement to manually input the connection config data. RedisInsight states in their docs to something similar I have to use their API which i'm not sure how to go about in K8s. Perhaps a sidecar is not the option to use. I don't know.

Comment: I see, if I understand correctly - the API allows you to programmatically add a DB to the RedisInsight UI, but not to a different application. I'm not why are injecting the config file using a dedicated tool instead of just using a configmap. Is it because you don't want to store the secret for the DB there?